# Case Class inheritance

Tags: scala, inheritance

I have a class hierarchy in which I would have preferred to have three levels of case classes:
I was only peripherally aware that Case Classes do not admit inheritance: but I smelled the coffee on this one.

So, presently I have:

```
"Grandparent" : Abstract class that extends Product
"Kids":  Case Classes  (concrete  - these are instantiated within the framework)
"Grandkids"  Case classes  (not allowed)
```

Now there is a lot of boilerplate around the framework that needs various aspects of Case Classes: so I am reluctant to go and convert the "Kid" to a non-case class.  In that scenario at the least I need to implement (for the purposes of the framework):

- the Product interface methods
- the copy() method
- the companion Object with at minimum the apply/unapply.

My concern on implementing these is: it will lead to a lot more code that has to be analyzed by my reviewers and later maintained.

Any thoughts on how to mitigate the code bloat impact of the non-inheritance restriction of Case Classes?

Comment: Why do you need them to be case classes? Can you just use classes? This question is hard to understand because you haven't given any code that uses these types.

Comment: I don't know the relation between `Grandparent` and the other classes. Anyway, you can make a `trait` that implements most of the `Kids`'s methods and fields, and define `case class Kids extend KidsTrait`, `case class Grandkids extends KidsTrait`. Or `trait GrandkidsTrait extend KidsTrait`, `case class Kids extend KidsTrait`, `case class Grandkids extend GrandkidsTrait`.

Comment: @Naetmul   Yes I did end up in one version doing something along the lines of what you say here - though I used abstract classes instead. If you want to make an answer I will award. In the meantime I am putting my own response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of along the lines of a couple of the comments - especially @naemul: I have converted the "children" level (middle level of the 3-tier hierarchy) into a combination of (abstract classes/concrete classes).

```
                        GrandParent (abstract class)
                             |
                       Abstract Kids
                       /          \
Concrete Kids (case classes)       \
                                  Concrete Grandkids (case classes)
```